# BASH script matching a glob at the begining of a string

Tags: string, bash, matching

I have folders in a directory with names giving specific information. For example:

```
[allied]_remarkable_points_[treatment]

[nexus]_advisory_plans_[inspection]

....
```

So I have a structure similar to this: `[company]_title_[topic]`. The script has to match the file naming structure to variables in a script in order to extract the information:

```
COMPANY='[allied]';
TITLE='remarkable points'
TOPIC='[treatment]'
```

The folders do not contain a constant number of characters, so I can't use indexed matching in the script. I managed to extract `$TITLE` and `$TOPIC`, but I can't manage to match the first string since the variable brings me back the complete folders name.

```
FOLDERNAME=${PWD##*/}
```

This is the line is giving me grief:

```
COMPANY=`expr $FOLDERNAME : '\(\[.*\]\)'`
```

I tried to avoid the greedy behaviour by placing ? in the regular expression:

```
COMPANY=`expr $FOLDERNAME : '\(\[.*?\]\)'`
```

but as soon as I do that, it returns nothing

Any ideas?

Comment: An example input/output pair is worth a million words (of course more than one is better).

Comment: Quote `$FOLDERNAME` to avoid the brackets from being treated as glob characters following the expansion, but see my answer for how to avoid `expr` altogether in `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expr` isn't needed for regular-expression matching in `bash`.

```
[[ $FOLDERNAME =~ (\[[^]]*\]) ]] && COMPANY=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Use `[^]]*` instead of `.*` to do a non-greedy match of the bracketed portion. An bigger regular expression can capture all three parts:

```
[[ $FOLDERNAME =~ (\[[^]]*\])_([^_]*)_(\[[^]]*\]) ]] && {
    COMPANY=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    TITLE=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    TOPIC=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash has built-in string manipulation functionality.

```
for f in *; do
    company=${f%%\]*}
    company=${company#\[}  # strip off leading [
    topic=${f##\[}
    topic=${f%\]}          # strip off trailing ]
    :
done
```

The construct `${variable#wildcard}` removes any prefix matching `wildcard` from the value of `variable` and returns the resulting string.  Doubling the `#` obtains the longest possible wildcard match instead of the shortest.  Using `%` selects suffix instead of prefix substitution.

If for some reason you do want to use `expr`, the reason your non-greedy regex attempt doesn't work is that this syntax is significantly newer than anything related to `expr`.  In fact, if you are using Bash, you should probably not be using `expr` at all, as Bash provides superior built-in features for every use case where `expr` made sense, once in the distant past when the `sh` shell did not have built-in regex matching and arithmetic.

Fortunately, though, it's not hard to get non-greedy matching in this isolated case.  Just change the regex to not match on square brackets.

```
COMPANY=`expr "$FOLDERNAME" : '\(\[[^][]*\]\)'`
```

(The closing square bracket needs to come first within the negated character class; in any other position, a closing square bracket closes the character class.  Many newbies expect to be able to use backslash escapes for this, but that's not how it works.  Notice also the addition of [double quotes around the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable).)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not adverse to using `grep`, then:

```
COMPANY=$(grep -Po "^\[.*?\]" $FOLDERNAME)
```